# PHP Ratchet NGINX Failed WebSocket connection handshake error response code: 502

Tags: php, nginx, websocket, wss, ratchet

Has anybody successfully gotten the [php ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world)  library working with NGINX using WSS. Am really struggling with it. I have the ratchet server running on port 8081. I can confirm that the socket server is listening on port 8081 and I can connect no problem using the ws protocol with no issue.

`var conn = new WebSocket('ws://connect.mydomain.net:8081');`

Now to configure WSS andhave NGINX to proxy to this I have the following NGINX configuration

```
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default Upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    upstream socket{
        server localhost:8081;
        #server connect.mydomain.net:8081;
    } 

    location /ws/ {
            #proxy_pass "http://socket";
            proxy_pass "https://connect.mydomain.net:8081";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
            keepalive_timeout 86400s;
            proxy_buffers 8 32k;
            proxy_buffer_size 64k;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            reset_timedout_connection on;
        }
```

Yet when I try to connect using

`var conn = new WebSocket('wss://connect.mydomain.net/ws/');`

I get failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

Can anyone please direct highlight anything I may be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was SELinux not allowing outbound connections

Running the following fixed my issue...

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

Seems like an obvious thing that all docs an similar issues on her seem to omit